# PHP - Solr API compatible with SOLR 3.x?

Tags: php, solr

Anyone know for certain if the PHP Solr API is compatible with SOLR 3.x? The only concrete compatibility I can see is from PHP SOLR [intro page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.solr.php). I also checked the [PECL SOLR page](http://pecl.php.net/package/solr) (and changelog), and found no references either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know it is compatible with Solr 3.X. I have been using the PHP Solr API with a Solr 3.4 instance and have not had any issues.

Comment: Awesome, basically that's all I was looking for. Looking to upgrade from http://code.google.com/p/solr-php-client/, and wanted to be sure that I wasn't conducting an exercise in futility. Thanks.